# Polymer paper-collapse item change class of parent

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a Polymer `<paper-collapse-item>` inside a `<div>` inside another `<div>`. When the `<paper-collapse-item>` is opened, I want to change add another class to the `<div class="container">`. But Polymer tells me the function is undefined. Right now I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="container> 
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div class="box" onclick="[[_expandBox()]]">
        <paper-collapse-item class="header" header="">
            <p class="longText">Some long text</p>
        </paper-collapse-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'text-page',

      _expandBox: function() {
        var exp = this.getElementsByClassName("header")[0];
        var expPar = this.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].parentNode;
        if (exp.hasAttribute(opened)) {
          expPar.className += " paropen";
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

So how I can I call the function properly and make it add a class to the container?

**EDIT**

I've made some changes to the entire setup for different reasons. Still left with this issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="container> 
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <collapse-item opened="{{opened}}" on-tap="_expandBox(opened)"></collapse-item>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'text-page',

      _expandBox: function(opened) {
        var exp = this.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
        if (opened) {
          exp.className += " paropen";
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

This tells me that: *listener method `_expandBox(opened)` not defined*

Thanks for helping me learn. I'm new to Polymer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Polymer Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#annotated-listeners), you have to write "on-" followed by gesture event type. You have to remove brackets within event handler too. In your case:

```
<div class="box" on-click="_expandBox">
```

**EDIT:**

On on-tap event declaration you must to add a listener, in this case `on-tap="_expandBox"` (without parameters). When the event *tap* occurs, an event object is passed automatically to the function as the first parameter:

```
_expandBox: function(event) {
    console.log(event.detail);
}
```

Your code could be:

HTML:

```
<div class="container> 
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <collapse-item id="collapseItem" on-tap="_expandBox" opened="[[_functionWithParamsThatChangesThis(param1, param2, ...)]]"></collapse-item>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'text-page',

      _expandBox: function() {
        var exp = this.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
        if (this.$.collapseItem.opened) {
          exp.className += " paropen";
        }
      }

      _functionWithParamsThatChangesThis(param1, param2, ...) {
        if (param1, param2, ...) return true;
        return false;
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: True, actually `on-tap` would be better. But there is still an error in the code so it does not work.

Comment: Could you show me the complete error? Have you removed brackets on handler?

Comment: The errow is `listener method _expandBox(opened) not defined` but I also made some additional changes for other reasons so I have updated the above question.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: I have upvoted it but do not have enough reputations for it to show up yet. It says they are recorded. I just need one more person to upvote one of my questions. :-)

Comment: Ah ok perfect ;)